# Display error when adding same item into JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I using detaful table model

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
```

and I row count

```
int Row = model.getRowCount();
```

Here is which I add row and wish to diplay error when adding same items.

```
if (Row > 0) {

               for(i=0;i<Row; i++){
                   if(jTable1.getValueAt(i,0).equals(name.getText())){       
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't add same item");
               }
               }
    }else if (Row <99) {
        model.addRow(new Object[] {name.getText(),address.getText(),Integer.parseInt(age.getText())});
    }
```

I guess wrong at if else statement?
Because I can add the 1st row and I can't add for 2nd row.

Thanks for help

Comment: For better help sooner, post your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. This allows users to copy/paste and reproduce your issue.

Comment: looks like as endless loop ended outoffmemoryexception

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have in your other variables, but I guess you have a discrepancy between product_id and name, perhaps?

Wouldn't it be more like

```
if(jTable1.getValueAt(i,0).equals(name.getText())){
```

UPDATE:

Try rewriting it like this:

```
int Row = model.getRowCount();
int boolean exists = false;
for(i=0;i<Row; i++){
   if(jTable1.getValueAt(i,0).equals(name.getText())){       
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't add same item");
      exists = true;
      break;
   }       
}


if (!exists && Row < 99) {
     model.addRow(new Object[] {name.getText(),address.getText(),Integer.parseInt(age.getText())});
}
```

Comment: yeah..my bad..i post the wrong 1..that should be name.getText(), I've update alr.

Comment: Can you then tell me, what type is name.getText()? is it a String?

Comment: Note, that you don't go into the else block if there is an existing row. I assume it just doesn't add the row, not complaining?

Comment: Essentially, you would probably want to break your problem into two.. 1) Establish if name already exists, and set a boolean. 2) If if boolean is false and rowcount less than 99 then add..

Comment: erm, after add the 1st row it doesn't add the 2nd row with different items.

Comment: yeah,it works ~ thank you

and for the line : int boolean exists = false;
should be change to <boolean exists = false;> right?

Comment: yeah..thanks for the explanation, I all combine in 1 and confuse that why can't add..thanks for the help anyway